# more capabilities in App Hub than in WMAppManifest.xml

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, capability, app-hub

I have developed an app using Silverlight XNA, with AdDuplex (for Silverlight 1.2.3) and Scoreloop  (Core Social 1.2.0).

I have defined capabilities of my app in `WMAppManifest.xml` as

```
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING"/>
    <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB"/>
    <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE"/>
</Capabilities>`
```

and every function works properly. (Sorry I do not know how to type in `<` here. Please help me edit it.)

However, after I submitted it, it shows in App Hub as

```
Required Device capabilities
data services 
music and video library
web browser 
owner identity 
XNA framework 
Silverlight framework 
phone identity 
trial
```

Though I later run the Markeplace Test Kit, it shows the same thing.

My question are:

Where do `owner identity` and `web browser` come from?

Why does App Hub override my decision?

Comment: FYI, 4 spaces before each line you want to use code formatting for. Alternatively, select the entire block and click the `{ }` formatting button and it will do it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capabilities are recalculated for you when you submit, [as described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg180730%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). As I understand it, undeclared capabilities will be added but unused capabilities will not be removed.

`owner identity` is almost certainly coming from either your ad framework or the social framework, and is determined by any reference to the `Microsoft.Phone.Info.UserExtendedProperties` class (including from any libraries you reference).

`web browser` is also likely coming from one of those two frameworks and is determined by a direct reference to the `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser` class.

For a full list of how each capability is determined, open `%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\Marketplace\Rules.xml` in your favourite text editor.

Comment: Is there a way to force limited capabilities?